# Ruby on Rails, when user not accepts terms show alert with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Ruby on Rails app I have form that looks like this:

```
= simple_form_for @reservation do |f|
  = f.input :terms, as: :boolean 
  = f.submit t('reservation.next'), class: "btn btn-default pull-right"
```

In my model I have virtual attribute terms:

```
validates :terms, acceptance: true, on: :create, allow_nil: false
attr_accessor :terms
```

Now when user not accept the terms application redirect it back with flash error.
But now I want when user not accept regulation the submit button is disabled. Is there any way to do this by JQuery?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "accept regulation" must be a checkbox, then enable / disable submit button on click of checkbox.

Comment: But when I do $('input.btn').attr('disabled', false) my submit button dissappear but I want only to can't clicked it.

Comment: check if somewhere you are calling hide on button or changing its CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the job. You'll need to change the jQuery selectors in this example (`#your_reservation_terms_checkbox` and `#your_submit_button`) to correctly to match the actual `id`s of those elements.

```
= simple_form_for @reservation do |f|
  = f.input :terms, as: :boolean
  = f.submit t('reservation.next'), class: "btn btn-default pull-right"

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input#your_reservation_terms_checkbox').on('change', function(){
      checked = $(this).is(':checked');
      $('#your_submit_button').prop('disabled', !checked);
      $('.warning-message').remove()
      if(!checked){
        $('#your_submit_button').before('<span class="warning-message">You must accept the terms</span>');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "accept regulation" is checkbox, then write a logic to enable and disable submit button on click of checkbox using jQuery :

Use unique `id` for `checkbox` and submit `button`.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="accept" id="accept"/>accept regulation

<input type="submit" value="click me" id="submitBtn" disabled/>


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#accept').on("change",function(){
        var checkboxChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('#submitBtn').prop('disabled',!checkboxChecked);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ncXfp/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample example on how to do it

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox_id" />
<input type="button" id="button_id" value="Submit" />

$('#checkbox_id').click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#button_id').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('#button_id').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/239L6/)**